# Rails 4- Devise custom controller test error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, devise, minitest

I am attempting to setup a new Rails project and encountering some difficulty with minitest, specifically with devise. I am trying to use custom controllers for devise, but am currently unable to test them. Right now I am just trying to get started, so my tests are empty. As soon as I run the first test it throws this error.

My controller file ('app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb')

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
      # clear_respond_to
      # respond_to :json
    end
```

My test file ('test/controllers/users/registrations_controller_tests.rb')

```
    require 'test_helper'

    class Users::RegistrationsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

      def setup
        # @current_user = users(:one)
      end

      test 'POST #create will register a new user with a valid email and matching passwords' do
        # params = {
        #   user: {
        #     email: 'test_email@mydomain.com',
        #     password: 'password',
        #     password_confirmation: 'password',
        #     format: :json
        #   }
        # }
        # post :create, params
        # binding.pry
      end

    end
```

The error:

```
    1) Error:
    RegistrationsControllerTest#test_POST_#create_will_register_a_new_user_with_a_valid_email_and_matching_passwords:
    ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "controllers" does not exist
    LINE 5:                WHERE a.attrelid = '"controllers"'::regclass
                                              ^
    :               SELECT a.attname, format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod),
                         pg_get_expr(d.adbin, d.adrelid), a.attnotnull, a.atttypid, a.atttypmod
                    FROM pg_attribute a LEFT JOIN pg_attrdef d
                      ON a.attrelid = d.adrelid AND a.attnum = d.adnum
                   WHERE a.attrelid = '"controllers"'::regclass
                     AND a.attnum > 0 AND NOT a.attisdropped
                   ORDER BY a.attnum



    Error:
    RegistrationsControllerTest#test_POST_#create_will_register_a_new_user_with_a_valid_email_and_matching_passwords:
    NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

I have attempted dropping and recreating the database, and have run rake db:test:prepare, all to no avail. I don't know where this error is originating from.

I am seeking advice on how to resolve this issue so I can progress with my testing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was entirely my own doing, as expected. I had at one point typed in `rails g devise controllers user` instead of `rails g devise:controllers user`. Consequently, rails did exactly what I told it to do and created files for a controller model, which of course doesn't actually exist. I had removed most of those files, but found a couple more hiding within the folders. Now that I have found and deleted the rest of those files my tests are working as expected.